# Submit form to different actions with in one form

Tags: php, forms, post

I have one form:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
```

And 2 button

```
<button name='button1'></button>
<button name='button2'></button>
```

What I want is on click `button1` then form post to index.php, but on click of `button2` then form post to index2.php.

OR

Click two button form post to index.php, after index.php post array to index2.php. I'm not use GET function!

Comment: I am pretty sure that you have to use Javascript for this as you got to make changes to the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use this by using jquery like below

```
<form method="POST" id="main_form">
    <button name='button1' id="btn_1"></button>
    <button name='button2' id="btn_2"></button>
</form>

$("#btn_1").click(function(){
   $("form#main_form").attr("action","index.php");
   $("form#main_form").submit();
});

$("#btn_2").click(function(){
   $("form#main_form").attr("action","index2.php");
   $("form#main_form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

remove action in your form This will only redirect to index.php.

```
<form method="POST" >
<button name='button1' onclick=my();></button>
<button name='button2'onclick=my1();></button>
</form>
<script>
 function my() {
  window.location.href = 'index.php';
  }   
  function my1() {
  window.location.href = 'index2.php';
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you submit form to two d/t urls but try doing something like this:

Add these two submit buttons with in your form.

```
<input type = "submit"  name='submit1' value = "submit1" />
<input type = "submit"  name='submit2' value = "submit2" />
```

So when the user clicks submit button one, the variable `name=submit1` will be submitted to the server.

When the user clicks submit button two, the variable `name=submit2` will be submitted to the server.

Then on your server side you can do something like this:

```
if(is_set($_POST['submit1']) && $_POST['submit1'] == 'submit1'){
   //code
}else if(is_set($_POST['submit2']) && $_POST['submit2'] == 'submit2'){
   //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doPreview()
    {
        form=document.getElementById('idOfForm');
        form.target='_blank';
        form.action='<?php echo Base_dir . 'email/create'; ?>';
        form.submit();
        form.action='#';
        form.target='';
    }
</script>
```

And use onclick in button :)

Thanks all!